# Javascript: Issue with if/for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get my function to return certain responses depending on how many vowels the input has. However, it seems that it copies the entire word into the new array.

```
Expected: die JÃ¼rgen, instead got: der JÃ¼rgen
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm messing up?

```
function derDieDas(wort){
  var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'ä', 'ö', 'ü'];
  var newArray = [];
  for(var i in wort) {
    for(var j in vowels) {
      if(i === j) {
        newArray[newArray.length] = i;
      };
    };
  };
  if(newArray.length < 2) {
    return 'das ' + wort;
  } else if(newArray.length < 4) {
    return 'die ' + wort;
  } else {
    return 'der ' + wort;
  }
};
```

Comment: Why are you _guessing_ what the loops do? Put `console.log(newArray);` after the loops and see what the result is in the browser console (press F12). It’s supposed to be `if(wort[i] === vowels[j]){ newArray[newArray.length] = wort[i]; }` inside the loops.

Comment: you are comparing indices, not values.

Comment: In JS there are tons of Array methods at your service that you can use.

Comment: Use `for (var item of iter) {  }` or `Array.prototype.forEach` instead of `for (var item in obj) {  }` loops for arrays to avoid coming across object properties. You can also use `Array.prototype.push` to add an item to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing indices

```
if (i === j) {
```

instead of elements of the arrays like

```
if (wort[i] === vowels[j]) {
```

Comment: LIke you and Xufox said, I was comparing the wrong things. I ended up replacing the array of vowels with a string of vowels instead. You would still refer to the string as vowels[j] instead of [j] right?

Comment: just `[j]` make no sense, because it returns a **string** with the value of `j` inside, because it uses [`Array#toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString)